# Codeigniter returns view with null variable

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, post

When i post the data from the other form , and when i test it in print($id)it works, but when i pass it in the view, when the view loads , it returns as null.

Here is my code :

Jquery post

```
function viewAccount(orId)
{
    account_id=orId;

    // alert(account_id);

    var postData={
        "id":account_id
    };

    $.post(base_url+"admin/viewAccount", postData).done(function(data){
        inlcudeViews('admin/viewAccount');
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
function viewAccount()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $data =  array('id' => $id);

    // print_r($data); IT WORKS TILL HERE
    $this->load->view('admin/viewAccount', $data);

}
```

View:

```
// HERE IS WHERE I GET A NULL VARIABLE
var data='<?= $id ?>';
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `alert` in `viewAccount` view you just need to `print` or `echo` your `$id` like,

```
<?php
   echo isset($id) ? $id : '';
?>
```

Also, verify you have already enable PHP short tags in `php.ini`. If your are using `<?= $id ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Your Jquery and View is perfect. But in Controller you have to write

```
$this->load->view('admin/viewAccount', $data[0]);
```

**instead of**

```
$this->load->view('admin/viewAccount', $data);
```

**or you can write**

```
function viewAccount()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $data['id'] =$id;
    // print_r($data); IT WORKS TILL HERE
    $this->load->view('admin/viewAccount', $data);
}
```

Comment: I already tryed both methods of assigning a value to a array , they both are the same and didnt work. somehow it doesnt work like this, mby its a problem because i include the view instead of refreshing and going to that view :)
thanks

Comment: @saty Hey bro sorry... :( but i didn't know that you answered the same.

Comment: @DeepParekh `$data['id']=$id;` is same as `$data =  array('id' => $id);` so its not an answer, its just another way to assigning in array variable

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your `id` into `data array` like below

**Controller**

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$data['id']=$id;
//print_r($data); IT WORKS TILL HERE
$this->load->view('admin/viewAccount', $data);
```

Comment: I did my firend, passing a variable in an array is the same , my method or yours :)

Comment: No i couldn't  get the ID , it comes as null :/

Comment: I got the id in the controller, but i couldnt pass it in the VIEW

Comment: just write `<?php echo $id; ?>` in view file with my code and check what you got???

Comment: @Saty `$data['id']=$id;` is same as `$data =  array('id' => $id);` so its not an answer, its just another way to assigning in array variable

Comment: @Saty i get null , nothing just white space ' '.
Rohan is right !

Answer (score 0):

You have not echo $id in your javascript this should be like `echo $id`:

Update here :

```
// HERE IS WHERE I GET A NULL VARIABLE
var data='<?php echo $id; ?>';
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert(data);
    });
```

Comment: Its not correct to use `<?php echo $data["id"]; ?>`. Use just `<?php echo $id; ?>`

Comment: yes no need to write echo when we write "<?=" like <?= $id;?> and $data['id'] is not the correct to use.

Comment: @RohanKumar actually i am using cakephp so it write like that so

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the fast responses, noone of the answers above work.
I managed to find a solution , but its completely different method i just put id as a global variable.
But i would be still interested in the answer of this, i assume it will help other people to

Comment: see my edited answer if it helpful then accept the answer.